# IK rig going incredibly wrong

Tags: rigging, rigify, inverse-kinematics

Whenever i edit my rig the ik goes rogue ,this problem is very prolonged , i am having this for long time, for example following are the two pictures of the rig in the edit mode , before editing and after editing
i donot see this problem on online tutorials , if there is some problem with the edit , then please tell

### Before Editing [image: nv]

### After Editing

[image]

### Rig in posemode before editing

This is what i was expecting from the edited version of the rig which you can see in the picture number 2
[image]

### pose after editing

[image]

THis is posted around 2 days ago and there is no activity on this question even if i edit it to come up , is there no body that will help me?

Comment: hello please share your armature: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: 99.9% sure you have a circular dependency. Open the window -> console and check, please.

Comment: @moonboots this is just the simple rigify addon armature and a simple ik on the leg , nothing to share

Comment: @FrederikSteinmetz can you please elaborate on what you mean , i am frustrated from this faulty rig

Comment: @FrederikSteinmetz The problem still persists , there is nothing in the console only the deletion of my cube is mentioned

Comment: Deleting the cube should not show up there, upper left Window -> Toggle System Console

Comment: Thats where i am - the black "Command prompt like" window